# Broadcast pop up message when iPhone devices comes in the iBeacon range

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I have developed one application which will get connected with the iBeacon & will give notifications while user enters or exits from the iBeacon range.

**Important Note :**

- I am using the inbuilt `CoreLocation` class to handle the iBeacon devices

Now with iBeacon device what I want to achieve is whenever any iOS device comes in the range of iBeacon it will send the pop up message to that device. It will be normal welcome message.

Kindly note that I do not want any application to get installed on that device. Still iBeacon should be able to detect the device through Bluetooth & send pop up message.

My question is, This is feasible ? If so how can It be able to send the pop up message to the any iPhone device that comes into range ?

Any hint or guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is not possible, that would be a really big security issue if anyone could send you a popup

Comment: @Mayur, did you find some answer to this question?

Comment: @m1sh0 its not possible in iOS right now but in android yes its still possible

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no way to trigger such a message if you don't have installed an application which listening for this.

Comment: Are you sure bro ? than how when we enters to the shopping mall, We receives notifications of offers ?

Comment: on ios device without having an application to do it? Can you show an example of this?

Comment: I don't have an example bro but I am doing research on it

Comment: I think something that can be done, is to send you a message through the telecom company if the telecom detects you on a specific cell. The best that you can do is to have an app with beacon and/or network detection that send notifications. If you found a way how to send stuff to all ios devices I will be happy to know it.